# Classification procedure using Minimum Redundancy Maximum Relevance (MRMR)

Tags: classification, feature-selection

After selecting features with MRMR (by quantizing original feature space of training data), should we classify the test data using quantized values or original values?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the quantized values, what was the point of using the MRMR? from what I understand, it helps you "select a feature subset set that best characterizes the statistical property of a target classification variable" (sounds like PCA). So after you have done that, it helps your classifier to focus on the more important features.